# How do you access the request/response from an app router page?

Tags: next.js, app-router

In the pages router, you could create a `getStaticProps` function, which would then feed props into your component function.  `getStaticProps` in turn got an argument of the request and response objects, so you could pass any information you wanted from them to your page.

In the app router, there is no longer a `getStaticProps` function: you're just supposed to fetch your data from the component function.  However, the component function *doesn't* get passed the request/response, so it seems impossible to access them now.

Is there some other mechanism to access the request/response objects in the latest version of Next.js?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration

Comment: seems related posts: \ 
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/42732 Access Request Object in New App Directory Page Route #42732 \ 
https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/yef3xc/nextjs_13_how_do_you_access_the_request_object/ \ 
seems not possible idk why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on jonrsharpe's comment, it looks like there no longer is a way to access the request from a page.

You can use an API route instead (which does get the full request), or you can use the [`headers`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers) and [`cookies`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies) functions (from the `next/headers` package) to access just those parts of the request ... but it seems it's impossible to get any other information from the request, or to get the request object itself.

Comment: Note that you can you an API route not only in the `/api` folder, but anywhere really. Just use a `route.ts` file instead of a `page.tsx`.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to access the request and response objects, you should use server-side rendering methods like `getServerSideProps`. However, `getServerSideProps` is not available at the `_app.js` level, as it's designed to work with individual pages.

To access request/response objects or perform server-side logic at the app level, you may consider creating an API route in the `pages/api` directory, where you can access the `req` and `res` objects directly:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  // You have access to the request and response objects here
}
```

This is the only thing that comes to mind, otherwise you may need to re thing your approach.